# what is c:out used for in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I have seen something like

```
<c:out   something

</c:out>
```

what is this used for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is used to print server-side variables while taking HTML/XML escaping into account. When applying this on user-controlled input (request parameters, headers, cookies, saved data, etc), this will prevent your site from potential [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) [attack](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html) holes.

If the data-to-be-displayed is in no way controlled by the enduser and you're using JSP 2.0 or newer (`web.xml` is declared as Servlet 2.4 or newer and the container supports it), then you can also just use

```
${bean.property}
```

instead of

```
<c:out value="${bean.property}" />
```

#### See also:

- [XSS prevention in Java/JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-java/)
- [How does an XSS attack really work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364427/how-xss-attack-really-works/)

Answer (score 2):

This tag is used to output data directly to the page.  It is useful if you have a variable you want to display to the user.  By default `c:out` escapes html characters so that you are protected against an XSS attack.

Another feature is that you can provide a "default" string in the event that your expression is null:

```
<c:out value="${foo.bar}">Foobar is null!</c:out>
```

Answer (score 1):

`c:out` can be used to print variables AND escapes HTML characters so is safer.

It is also useful for displaying default text when the variable is null.

e.g.

```
<c:out value="${variable}">variable is null</c:out>
```

will display "variable is null" if variable is not set.